# Multiple echoed delete-edit buttons in PHP event listener

Tags: php, mysql, button

I am trying a trivial PHP assignement. I am running my own SQL server locally and I have created a DB on it called `student`. This database contains many tables. One of them is called `announcement`. The fields of this table are `id, date, subject, text`.

I am asked to display those announcements to a user that has the authority to delete and/or modify those entries of the DB. Each entry needs to be seperated from the next one and each entry has to have it's own `Delete` and `Edit` button. New entries can also be added to the database so the # of entries currently on the DB is not known.

So far I have done something like this:

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("student",$db);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcement",$db);
    $announcementID = 1;
    WHILE($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<br><h2>Announcement No".$announcementID."</h2>";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"Delete\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Edit\" value=\"Edit\"><br>";
        echo "<br>Date: ".$myrow["date"];
        echo "<br>Subject: ".$myrow["subject"];
        echo "<br>Text: ".$myrow["text"];
        $announcementID=$announcementID+1;
        echo '<br><hr />';
    }
 ?>
```

This is a part of a larger php file that displays a webpage with the entries properly formatted.

Although I do create the separate buttons needed for each distinct announcement I do not think this can work out since I can't create an `ActionListener` (forgive me but I do not know how this is called in PHP) for those buttons and I am not even sure it is possible considering that all of those buttons will have the same name. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP to be able to indetify that the user has clicked the button, you would need to surround the each row of inputs.
I've improved your code a little, as we need to pass over the ID of the announcement to the delete-record.php script for it to be able to identify which record to delete from the table.

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("student",$db);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcement",$db);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<form action="delete-record.php" method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $myrow["id"] . '">';
    echo "<br><h2>Announcement No".$announcementID."</h2>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"delete\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" value=\"edit\"><br>";
    echo "<br>Date: ".$myrow["date"];
    echo "<br>Subject: ".$myrow["subject"];
    echo "<br>Text: ".$myrow["text"];
    echo '<br><hr />';
    echo "</form>";
}
```

And then in the delete-record.php you can go with this:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['delete'])) {
    $announcementid = $_POST['id'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM announcement WHERE id = $announcementid");
}
```

For future reference, instead of using `$announcementID = $announcementID+1;` you can simply use the [post-incremental operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) `$announcementID++;`

I also suggest you to read up on [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)'s prepared statements to secure yourself against SQL Injections and other SQL vulnerabilities.

Comment: This seems to work although a bit differently that what I expected. It deletes the next row in the table instead of the correct one. I will try to find out why.

Comment: Correction! It deletes the last row, not the next one.

Comment: I removed the entire $announcementID variable as you should always go for what the table says. This passes over the ID from the current looped row in the table to delete-record.php script, so unless you are still using $announcementID in your code, everything should be working fine.

Comment: Even when removing `$announcementID` the problem persists.

Comment: Take note of this line `echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $myrow["id"] . '">';` it's crucial for the script to work.

Comment: The line in my code is identical to this one. I can't find anything wrong with it yet the outcome is wrong.

Comment: You must've missed something. If you copy over the code entirely, it works flawlessly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47374/discussion-between-tom-jordell-and-theocharis-k)

Answer (score 0):

Create a form around each row with a Delete button

```
WHILE($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<form method='post' action='delete-record.php'>";
    echo "<br><h2>Announcement No".$announcementID."</h2>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"Delete\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Edit\" value=\"Edit\"><br>";
    echo "<br>Date: ".$myrow["date"];
    echo "<br>Subject: ".$myrow["subject"];
    echo "<br>Text: ".$myrow["text"];
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='formID' value='$announcementID' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete row'/>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo '<br><hr>';
    $announcementID=$announcementID+1;
}
```

Then in delete-record.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formID'])){
    // Delete record query here
}
...
```

Comment: This `echo "<input type='submit' value="Delete row"/>";` should either be `echo "<input type='submit' value=\"Delete row\" />";` or `echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete row' />";` - Notice how `Delete` is in blue?

Comment: Fixed That. I don't really like this solution because I feel like it's too many forms, but without having a checkbox or something to signify which row to delete it seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I wasn't questioning the question/answer, just the syntax ;-) - If the OP feels it's good and fits the bill, great!

Answer (score 0):

Make javascript redirection to delete script.

```
WHILE($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<br><h2>Announcement No".$announcementID."</h2>";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"Delete\" onClick=\"window.location='delete_announcement.php?announcemenID=".$announcementID."';\">"
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Edit\" value=\"Edit\" onClick=\"window.location='edit_announcement.php?announcemenID=".$announcementID."';\"><br>";
        echo "<br>Date: ".$myrow["date"];
        echo "<br>Subject: ".$myrow["subject"];
        echo "<br>Text: ".$myrow["text"];
        $announcementID=$announcementID+1;
        echo '<br><hr />';
    }
```

And `delete_announcement.php` connect to the DB and do

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM announcement WHERE announcemenID=" . $_REQUEST["announcemenID"],$db);
```

Don't forget to make sure that `$_REQUEST["announcemenID"]` only hold integers.

For edit you will need to create separate page `edit_announcement.php` with all the fields editable.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Javascript on this project. I need to stick strictly with PHP/HTML. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: In that case @Shizzle answer is your only option.